# momentJS wrong date convertion DD/MMM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have date:

```
"2019-10-16T04:34:14.000-0500"
```

and using `moment.utc("2019-10-16T04:34:14.000-0500").format("DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm")`

i get `10/15/2019 16:34`

what i want is `15/Oct/2019 16:34`

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I get "16/Oct/2019 09:34".  I cannot reproduce your result.  What version of momentjs are you using?

Comment: Same as above. Maybe try doing it in your F12 Debug console to confirm if there is some other auto formatting occurring.

Comment: You have to use timezone liberary of momentjs. You can convert it in specific timezone. right now moment is using your local timezone

Comment: Here is link: https://momentjs.com/timezone/
Go through documentation you will get desired output

Comment: @JanakPrajapati OP's lamenting a formatting problem, not a wrong date/time

Comment: just now i installed momentjs fresh installtion

Comment: Not reproducible. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tLhsc6fg/ . Are sure you a) gave us the right code in your example, and b) that's the only thing which is affecting the output?

Comment: ok when i console.log it looks ok but i am formating this field form api and then it is saved to .csv file maybe excel is formatting this date?

Comment: Maybe. CSV isn't exclusive to Excel. Open the CSV file in Notepad++ (or another text editor) and see what it really looks like in the raw file. Maybe also show us how you actually create and save the file, how you include this date in it. (P.S. in future learn to narrow down the problem - you should always isolate each section of code and test it when looking for issues like this. You assumed momentJS was at fault here when it wasn't, because you didn't check the direct output from that bit of code. Better root cause analysis needed...)

Comment: I am sure that saving to csv is messing thus up and i need to manually change cells format

Comment: Did you check in notepad like I said? The file itself might be fine. It might just be excel which is making a mess of it. You can change the format of the cells, sure, but next time you open it there will just be the same problem, because you cannot save formatting changes in a CSV. You would have to save it again in excel format for that to be preserved. But why not output the date in a more computer readable format such as yyyy-mm-dd then excel might cope with it better

Comment: @Amy but you get 9:34 so how to be sure that convertion is has the same date as input?? example 2019-10-21T12:43:37.000-0500 and i get =>10/21/2019 19:43 how to get 12:43??

Comment: I am in a different time zone than you are. The different time isn't important.

Comment: but i am my converted data to guys in diffrent timezone so they will have correct one? or i need t do something? this is not and issue?

Comment: @Exc it's only an issue if the timezone matters. They will see it in their local timezone. So the time will be correct for their location. It represents the same moment in time, just expressed in local terms. It depends how you want to display it to people. P.S. Read https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ as well

Comment: i think it will be good to convert it to utc and tell them that it is UTC time

Comment: For now, I think you should focus on the question that was asked: why the date isn't being formatted as expected.  If that was solved, I seem to have missed it.

Comment: yes it is not momntjs it is .csv